# How to identify meta key of an input field in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

What is meta key of an input field?

`<input class="f_age" value="" type="number" name="alg_wc_pif_global_1" id="alg_wc_pif_global_1" placeholder="" required="">`

is it `alg_wc_pif_global_1`

or

`_1`

or none of them?

Comment: it should logically be `alg_wc_pif_global_1` or may be `_alg_wc_pif_global_1` *(starting with an underscore)*, but not `_1`…